# How can I arrange the array by the value 4rth value of each line, highest to lowest?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

How can I arrange the array by the value 4rth value of each line, highest to lowest? I am pretty new to Python so I lack a lot of knowledge.

**Shape of Input**

```
panite,1,1800
ruby,2,100
diamond,0.75,900
emerald,3,250
amethyst,2,50
opal,1,300
sapphire,0.5,750
benitoite,1,2000
malachite,1,60
```

**My Python Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import numpy as np


def vault(dataFile):
    vault = []

    for l in dataFile.readlines():      
        attribute = l.split(",")
        vault.append(str(attribute[0]))
        vault.append(float(attribute[1]))
        vault.append(int(attribute[2]))
        vault.append(int(attribute[2])/float(attribute[1]))
    Vault = np.array(vault).reshape(-1,4)
    return(Vault)

def main():
    fileFound = False
    while not fileFound:
        fileName = input("File name containing jewel data: ")
        try:
            dataFile = open(fileName, "r")
            fileFound = True
        except:
            print("Could not find that file -- try again")
    knapsackCapacity = 5.00
    print (vault(dataFile))

main()
```

Comment: Need some example of input data/file, and expected output. Othwerise, difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah sorry cause I get the input from a file. The input is panite,1,1800
ruby,2,100
diamond,0.75,900
emerald,3,250
amethyst,2,50
opal,1,300
sapphire,0.5,750
benitoite,1,2000
malachite,1,60

Comment: Nobody said do my HW. It's Thanksgiving so I cannot ask my teacher nor my mentor for this so I though posting it here. I am not saying solve it, just asking some help on something I have never done or learned about in class before.